# How to assign value to LPVOID buffer of ReadFile

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, buffer, easyhook

I am developing a win32 API hook program.
Accordingly to my understanding, when a program calls ReadFile for a particular file, the content of that file is copied to lpBuffer(see the definition below),

ReadFile definition:

```
BOOL ReadFile(
  HANDLE       hFile,
  LPVOID       lpBuffer,
  DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

Now, my target is to alter this lpBuffer and fill it with provided content by me!
I am using EasyHook to hook ReadFile. I am not familiar with LPVOID type. I was able to alter the content for GetCurrentDirectory using the following code.

```
 string b = "C:\\my\\altered\\directory";
 DWORD returnLength  = b.length();
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i<b.length(); i++)
 {
    lpBuffer[i] = b[i];
 }
 lpBuffer[i++] = '\0';
```

GetCurrentDirectory definition:

```
DWORD GetCurrentDirectory(
  DWORD  nBufferLength,
  LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

How to do similar value assignment for ReadFile (LPVOID lpBuffer)?

Comment: Treat it as a pointer to the first element of an array of bytes, at least `nNumberOfBytesToRead` bytes in length. Just like you do for the `GetCurrentDirectory` override. You need to cast the pointer though.

Comment: `LPVOID` is a pointer to `void`. `void` is nothing. You can't make a `void`, but you can cast ANYTHING to a pointer to `void`, so you don't have to do anything other than get the pointer to the `string`'s character buffer: `ReadFile(handle, b.data(), ...)`. Unfortunately that doesn't make any sense logically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `LPVOID` typedef:

```
#define far
typedef void far *LPVOID;
```

The `far` macro is defined as nothing, I guess it's because of some historical reasons (baggage).
So you can almost directly treat the `LPVOID` as `void*`.

And now, suppose you have a `std::vector<uint8_t>` named `FakeData`, just:

```
if (nNumberOfBytesToRead < FakeData.size()) {
    SetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
    return FALSE;
}

memcpy(lpBuffer, FakeData.data(), FakeData.size());
*lpNumberOfBytesRead = FakeData.size();

SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);
return TRUE;
```

Comment: I think you're headed in the right direction here, but if I'm not 100% sure, you're probably you're not giving the asker enough of an explanation.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, I edited the answer for further explanation.

Comment: `string content = "altered content";
memcpy(lpBuffer, content, content.length());
`


Can I do something like this? Need to case content to const void, I guess

Comment: @MdSajid You can do this for text files, not recommended for binary files. And it should be `memcpy(lpBuffer, content.c_str(), content.length());`

Comment: I only perform this action on file type like "txt"

Comment: @MdSajid That's no problem.

Comment: @MdSajid Oops, don't forget to assign the size to `lpNumberOfBytesRead`, I have edited the answer.